# After git token was regenerated wrong user is being used, but correct in git config file

Tags: github

A fine grained token expired so I regenerated it.  But since doing that when I try to push to the repository it tells me access is denied and lists a username from a different github account that I have never used on this laptop.

How do I get it to use the other account again?

Running `git config global --list` in a new terminal and from inside the app folder both output the user I want it to use with the proper credentials, but when I try to run `git push` it denies it and lists a different user name.

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: It's also possible that git has cached credentials for the other GitHub account you described. Maybe you still have those in memory? To remove them, you can use the following command: `git credential-cache exit`.

Comment: It was being stored in the keychain

Comment: Answer was found here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1064197/how-to-switch-git-user-at-terminal#answer-1064244

Comment: Alright..... :) I didn't think my answer would help. (because it seemed very unlikely)

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri Never know it might help someone else, I appreciate you giving it a shot!